# xy points in the perimeter of a rotated ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

How can I calculate the $(x,y)$ position of every point on the perimeter of a rotated ellipse?

I have found the equations for a non-rotated ellipse

$x=a \cosθ$
$y=b \sinθ$

What are the formulas if my ellipse is rotated?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? Are there any particular points that you are stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x = a \,cos\theta \,cos\phi - b \,sin\theta \, sin \phi$$
$$y = a \,cos\theta \,sin\phi + b \,sin\theta \, cos \phi$$

Here $\phi$ is an angle of a rotation.